# Can you detect when an incrementing counter has reached N by AND'ing the expected set bits?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

With a incrementing counter, starting from zero, I can tell when 128 is reached by looking for a positive edge on bit:7.

I can detect when 129 is reached by looking for a positive edge on (bit:7 & bit:0)

I think that I can detect when 130 is reached by looking for a positive edge on (bit:7 & bit:1)

Can I AND all the expected set bits together to detect when an incrementing counter reaches a expected value?  This will be used to reset the counter.

Comment: There's a small error in your question: It's bit 7 and 0 for 129, as well as 7 and 1 for 130. (Assuming that the LSB is numbered as bit 0).

Comment: Are you going to reset the counter when you get to the count you're detecting? Otherwise if you detect 5 as bits 0 and 2, for example, you'll detect it again when the count reaches 13, 21, etc...

Comment: @JonathanS. Thanks, I've fixed that.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, I'll be resetting the counter.

Comment: @fadedbee you should include that information in your question post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this always works! The value you're checking for is the first one for which the AND gate will output a 1. This means that the AND gate detects when the counter first passes the expected value, and after that, it may or may not output additional pulses (which your circuitry will likely ignore).

It's really easy to prove why, too: If any of the other bits is set that you're not checking for, the value of the counter is already larger than the value you're expecting. So any value with additional bits set is *not* the first one which the AND gate detects.

For example, the value 130 is 1000'0010 in binary. If you AND only the two set bits in that value (bit #7 and bit #1), the AND gate will output a 1 for any value of the form "1xxx'xx1x". 130 is the smallest one of them (all of the x = 0), so it's the first one for which the AND gate will output a 1. Since the counter counts up starting at a value smaller than 130, you know that 130 is reached when the AND gate outputs a 1 for the first time.

This works regardless of the width of the counter and the value you're checking. It even works for down-counters if you check the cleared bits (0) instead of the set bits (1).

As Neil_UK mentioned in the comments, there might of course be glitches in the AND gate's output value when the counter switches from one value to the next, just like there might be glitches in the counter's output value itself. Ideally, the circuitry downstream from the AND gate should be synchronous logic clocked from the same clock as the counter, or otherwise qualified on that clock signal. Asynchronous logic might cause issues, as usual. This issue is, however, independent of the technique used to detect the desired counter value.

Comment: what about glitches? Let's say you want to detect 7 = 111. When the counter increments from 5 = 101 to 6 = 110, there may be a brief time when both lower bits are asserted, if the 2 bit goes true faster than the 1 bit goes false. The AND needs to be qualified by either sufficient propagation time after the clock pulse, or sufficient length of time asserted to not be a glitch.

Comment: @Neil_UK - I can fix this by combining this signal with the inverse of the clock which increments the counter.

Comment: @fadedbee yes, that's an implementation of 'sufficient time after the clock pulse'.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect any single value in a binary number using a wide-enough AND gate, plus inverters as necessary.

The AND gate will detect bits that are '1' while the inverters are needed for bits that are logic '0'.

So, for example, in digital logic the below circuit will detect 3-bit value 'n' being 110 binary.

Specific value ranges for a binary number can be detected by omitting inputs from the AND gate. So if the below circuit was a 2-input AND connected to n2 and n1, its output would be HIGH when n was 110 or 111 binary i.e. 6..7 decimal.

So to your question, an AND gate could detect when an 8-bit counter reached 129 decimal by ANDing just bits n7 and n1. The AND would in fact detect every odd number from 129 to 255 but, if counting up from under 128 for example, 129 is the first one reached and the 2-input AND is sufficient.

Using smaller-width gates like ANDs/ORs in this way has been done for a long time to save on gates.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsIEjam.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Downvoter: explanation?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it might be that we had a miscommunication of the question.  (I have since edited the question to make it clearer.)  My question specifically asked about an incrementing counter reaching a value (for the first time) and a logical shortcut that I wanted to confirm as correct.  Your answer is a good answer to the wider problem of identifying when a value is matched, but does not relate to my counter-specific question.

Comment: @fadedbee The second part of this answer addresses your specific use-case (incrementing counter). +1 to compensate a (imo) wrongful downvote.

Comment: @Velvet Yes it does, on re-reading.  Perhaps I saw the logic diagram and thought "that's not what I'm asking".  Upvoted.